# Product of a sequence tending to 0 and a sequence of random variables converging in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables and suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution. Let $a_n$ be a sequence of constants with $a_n \rightarrow 0$. Must $a_n X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely? Intuitively, it seems like this should be the case, since the $X_n$'s cannot be large with large probability (by the convergence in distribution), so the convergence of the $a_n$ should ensure the convergence of the $a_n X_n$ a.s. But, I am struggling to make this intuition into a formal proof. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, try $(X_n)$ i.i.d., not almost surely zero and distributed as $X$, and $(a_n)$ positive such that $a_n\to0$.

Then $\sum\limits_n\mathbb P(a_nX_n\geqslant 1)=\sum\limits_n\mathbb P(X\geqslant 1/a_n)$. Borel-Cantelli lemma indicates that if the latter series diverges then $a_nX_n\geqslant1$ infinitely often, almost surely, in particular, $a_nX_n$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely.

It remains to choose $(a_n)$ such that the series diverges. For example, if $X$ is standard exponential, then $a_n=1/\log n$ does it.

Comment: But there is convergence in probability.